# Can not install ATI Radeon Mobility 5470 lates driver

Tags: drivers, ati, graphics, radeon, fglrx

I installed Kubuntu 14.04 (64bit) on a laptop with ATI Radeon Mobility 5470 graphic card. Trying to install latest proprietary driver ([version 14.4](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux%20x86#amd-catalyst-packages)) installer says your card is not supported by this driver:
[image]

ATI says this driver [supports ATI Mobility Radeon™ HD 5000 Series](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDCatalyst14-4LINReleaseNotes.aspx). However supported operating systems are:

- Red Hat Enterprise Linux Suite 6.4 and 6.5
- SUSE® Linux Enterprise 11 SP3
- openSUSE 13.1
- **Ubuntu 12.04.3, 12.04.4 and 13.10**

So the last line this means that catalyst 14.4 is not supposed to work with Ubuntu 14.04? If so, what should I do now? (fglrx or xorg-xserver-ati is not an option)

Comment: HD5000 series is officially supported by ATI in the proprietary drivers, so if it does not work, report it as a bug to ATI. However, your card should be fully supported by the open source driver. If you are having any problems with the open source driver report them to ATI via the mailing list or bug tracker at http://wiki.x.org/wiki/radeon/